# C# Drawing 2D objects with events

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I need to draw several simple objects (polygons composed by lines and arcs, eventually placed on different layers) inside a form (or any other container) and then handle events like:

- right click on object
- zoom
- pan

Is there a library/framework that can handle my need or do I need to create my own?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

My polygons come from SDO tables exported from AutoCAD Map 3D and I need to create a simple application that can show them (with pan, zoom, etc) and enable simple operations on them (like viewing properties, insert a point, etc).

May be I should look for an AutoCAD OEM license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good example can be found on codeproject called [draw tools](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx)

It has samples of drawing a rectanlge, ellipse, dragging, stretching etc and can be extended to add other basic objects. We used the same framework to write a program called [Page Layout Pro](http://www.pagelayoutpro.com/).

Comment: I don't think it can fit my needs

Answer (score 0):

[Mindfusion](http://www.mindfusion.eu/diagramming.html) have a range of diagramming libraries which support what you want, but may well be too complicated for your needs (and expensive).